# addeventlistener mouseover slow at giving x and y value

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Hello guys so i just started learning about using canvas so i used this example and fiddle with the code but i just realise that when add eventlistener for mouse over and check it using console it very slow at giving the cordinate of the x and y value of the mouse, is the logic that i put to the code the problem? or is that just the problem with the browser? Thanks

here's the code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        *{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        canvas{
            border:1px solid black;
            height: 100%;
            widows: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas></canvas>
    <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');

    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

    var c = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var mouse = {
        x:undefined,
        y:undefined
    }

    window.addEventListener("mouseover",function(event){
        mouse.x = event.x;
        mouse.y = event.y;
        console.log(mouse)
    })

    function Circle(x,y,dx,dy,radius){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.dx = dx;
        this.dy = dy;
        this.radius = radius;

        this.draw = function(){
            c.beginPath();
            c.arc(this.x,this.y,this.radius,0,Math.PI * 2, false);
            c.strokeStyle ="red";
            c.fill();
            c.stroke();
        }
        this.update = function(){
            if(this.x + this.radius > window.innerWidth || this.x - this.radius < 0){
                this.dx = -this.dx;
            }
            if(this.y + this.radius > window.innerHeight || this.y - this.radius < 0){
                this.dy = -this.dy;
            }
            this.x += this.dx;
            this.y += this.dy;

            if(mouse.x - this.x < 50 && mouse.x - this.x > -50 && mouse.y - this.y < 50 && mouse.y - this.y > -50){
                this.radius += 1;
            }else if(this.radius > 2){
                this.radius -= 1;
            }
            this.draw();
        }
    }
    var arrayCircle = [];
    for(var j = 0; j < 100; j++){
        var radius = 30;
        var x = Math.random() * (innerWidth - radius * 2) + radius;
        var y = Math.random() * (innerHeight - radius * 2) + radius;
        var dx = (Math.random() - 0.5);
        var dy = (Math.random() - 0.5);
        arrayCircle.push(new Circle(x,y,dx,dy,radius))
    }
    function animate(){
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        c.fillStyle = "red";
        c.clearRect(0,0,window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight);
        for(var i =0; i < arrayCircle.length; i++){
            arrayCircle[i].update();
        }

    }
    console.log(arrayCircle)
    animate();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi! Could you please clarify the problem? Hard to get what you're asking.

Comment: the problem i am having is that the addeventlistener for mouse over it slow at giving me the x and y value of the mouse.

Comment: Seems fine to me https://jsfiddle.net/xf9wqtrv/

Comment: really? try to fullscreen the page

Comment: Animations seem slow but not the logging of the mouseover. Are you watching the console?

Comment: The `addEventListener` call is almost instantaneous. The call of the function passed to `addEventListener` is what may or may not be slow. Typically one refers to that as the "event handler". Just a heads up to prevent confusion in the future.

Comment: it seems that's not the case sorry for the confusion, i just fixed it by my own it seems that i put the wrong event to do what i want to achieve. next time i should look more to my code haha. thanks for the tips!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `mousemove` instead of `mouseover`, basically it is slow because it will only fire the `mouseover` function once mouse is out and then overed again.

```
 window.addEventListener("mousemove",function(event){
    mouse.x = event.x;
    mouse.y = event.y;
    console.log(mouse)
})
```

Comment: thanks man i fix it on my own too, it seems that i put the wrong event for my code.